# problem Regarding Treeview Control for windows form in c#

Tags: c#, xml

how to save tree view content into xml file.

i want to know how to edit,delete,insert treeview content at run time???

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/treeviewtoxml.aspx